# Importing recent NAVTEQ/HERE RDF Data into PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, import, oracle-dbms, rdf

I am trying to import a recent version of navteq data into a postgres DBMS. I have downloaded the 2014Q2 version of the data from https://here.flexnetoperations.com as well as Europe_RDF_rdf_customer_software. The RDF Software has a java program to import it into Oracle. I changed the JDBC settings to point to the Postgres DBMS. This did not help a lot, since the script uses sqlplus, a component of Oracle.

Are there any tools (from navteq/here) that could import all the navteq RDF data into postgres?

Answer (score 1):

I believe one can still import the data with the [Map_Tools](http://tcs.navteq.com/http-proxy/Map_Tools/). This is a java Program: once a connection is established from the map tool to a DB, one may start importing the data with Tools->RDF Installer